# Jackson deserialization nested json

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

How can I deserialize using java jackson lib a json like this using pojo:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "content": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1",
            "status": {
                "description": null,
                "internal_id": "status-none",
            },
            "internal_id": null,
            "ts_update": "2020-04-27T15:20:11.740+0000"
        }],
        "empty": false
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You'll need to create a set of POJOs and then use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to read object from the string.

Comment: You can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create java classes

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link, Oleg !